# GuzzleHttp sending weird request with weird http method

Tags: http, guzzle

I'm not sure if someone faced same problem but somehow inside my container an http request was generated with url `oauth/router` and http method `Offsetget`.

After some deep investigation without clear source of this request inside my container, just restarting the container with same code base, worked as expected.

I'm not sure if it's guzzle or something different, specially this weird http method.

Did anyone face same problem or have some explanation?

Thanks :)

Comment: "offsetGet" is one of the methods of [the ArrayAccess interface](https://www.php.net/arrayaccess) in case that gives anyone any clues